# jfreechart xyplot set background color for small area

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

i am use java to draw chart , and i want set background color for small area in xyplot . like: i want area from x axis (20 to 30) and y axis (10-20) set red color and do like this for the remaining, i am use valuemaker but not give me good solution because its fill long marker by color and i want only small area

this is my code:

```
private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

    /*JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Chart Index Sag",
            "Sag Duration",
            "Retained Voltage",
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            false,
            false,
            false
    );*/

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer rr = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    rr.setSeriesLinesVisible(2, true);
    rr.setSeriesShapesVisible(2, true);
    rr.setPaint(Color.red);

    // Point label
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setBaseFillPaint(Color.black);
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, false);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new LabelGenerator());
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    renderer.setPaint(Color.black);
    //plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    SymbolAxis symbolaxis1 = new SymbolAxis("Sag Duration", new String[] { "0","0.02","0.2", "0.5", "10" });
    symbolaxis1.setRange(0,6);
    symbolaxis1.setGridBandsVisible(false);

    SymbolAxis range = new SymbolAxis("Returned Voltage", new String[] { "0","0.2","0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "1" });
    range.setRange(0,5);
    range.setGridBandsVisible(false);

    plot = new XYPlot(dataset, symbolaxis1, range, renderer);
    plot.setDomainPannable(true);
    plot.setRangePannable(true);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    // Line curve
    plot.setDataset(0, dataset);
    plot.setDataset(1, dataset1);

    final Marker originalEnd = new ValueMarker(1);
    originalEnd.setPaint(Color.black);
    originalEnd.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addDomainMarker(originalEnd);

    final Marker v2 = new ValueMarker(2);
    v2.setPaint(Color.black);
    v2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addDomainMarker(v2);

    final Marker v3 = new ValueMarker(3);
    v3.setPaint(Color.black);
    v3.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addDomainMarker(v3);

    final Marker v4 = new ValueMarker(4);
    v4.setPaint(Color.black);
    v4.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addDomainMarker(v4);

    Marker r1 = new ValueMarker(1);
    r1.setPaint(Color.black);
    r1.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addRangeMarker(r1);

    Marker r2 = new ValueMarker(2);
    r2.setPaint(Color.black);
    r2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addRangeMarker(r2);

    Marker r3 = new ValueMarker(3);
    r3.setPaint(Color.black);
    r3.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addRangeMarker(r3);

    Marker r4 = new ValueMarker(4);
    r4.setPaint(Color.black);
    r4.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    plot.addRangeMarker(r4);

    float dash[] = {1, 1};
    float f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3 = 10;


    /*NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setRange(0, 2);
    domainAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.2));*/
    BasicStroke gridstroke = new BasicStroke(f1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, f2, dash, f3);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.blue);
    //plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.blue);
    plot.setDomainGridlineStroke(gridstroke);
    plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(gridstroke);
    final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
    chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(0, rr);
    chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(1, renderer);
    return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [`XYBoxAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYBoxAnnotation.html), maybe something like this:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
XYBoxAnnotation xyboxannotation = new XYBoxAnnotation(
    1, 1, 2, 2, new BasicStroke(0), new Color(0), new Color(0x30d0d0d0));
renderer.addAnnotation(xyboxannotation, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

[image: XY Box Annotation]